# Как работает озвучивание текста с помощью speechSynthesis?

Tags: javascript

Возникла необходимость реализовать озвучивание текста на сайте.
Для этого использовался метод speechSynthesis, но на некоторые вопросы, касающиеся работы функции, так и остались открытыми.
Хотелось бы узнать, на каком уровне работает данная функция? Есть предположение, что она работает на уровне браузера (при закрытии вкладки озвучивание продолжается, если не обработать этот в коде), но, никакого подтверждения этому так и не найдено.
Вопрос из этой же тематики - почему на вкладке не появляется динамик, когда происходит озвучивание? К примеру, когда на многих браузерах в какой-либо вкладке идет звуковое сопровождение (будь то музыка или фильм), на самой вкладке появляется значок динамика. При запуске озвучивания текста с помощью  speechSynthesis такого не происходит.
Возможно кто-нибудь сможет пролить свет на эту тему.

Код скрипта:

```
    <script>

        let description = document.getElementsByClassName('product-info__description')[0];
        let synth = window.speechSynthesis;
        let play = document.getElementsByClassName('play')[0];
        let utterance = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(description.innerText);
        utterance.lang = 'ru-Ru'
        let isSpeak = false;            

        window.onblur = () => {
            if (isSpeak === true) {
                synth.pause(utterance);
                play.innerText = '►';
                isSpeak = false;
            }
        }

        window.onunload = () => {
            synth.cancel(utterance); 
        }

        function speak(){
            if (isSpeak === false) {
                play.innerText = '■';
                isSpeak = true;
                synth.speak(utterance);
                synth.resume(utterance);
            } else if (isSpeak === true) {
                synth.pause(utterance);
                play.innerText = '►';
                isSpeak = false;
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Вы бы хотя бы уточнили, что за браузер. Конечно, мы догадываемся, что это Chrome, но лучше явно указать. Да и код было бы неплохо привести в пример.

Comment: к системной службе ОС обращается, очевидно. а значка нет - дак недоработка конкретных браузеров.

Comment: Тестирование проводилось во всех браузерах, и во всех отсутствовал знак динамика. Код скрипта добавила, там уже вместе с обработкой закрытия и перехода на другую вкладку.